# How to retrieve forgotten WordPress admin password?

Tags: wordpress

I want to get my WordPress blog up and running again (change the theme) but I have forgotten my password. I do not remember the username or email either.

Is there a way to retrieve this without having to reinstall WordPress and lose all my posts?

Comment: Self hosted or wordpress.com hosted?

Comment: He says "reinstall" Wordpress. Which might suggest that it is self hosted.

Comment: [Here's a mess of info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password) in the WP Codex on resetting using various methods.

Comment: I like this alot! Although Alexandre way I got through with first.

Comment: This question was posted during the early days of this site. Nowadays, questions about administering self-hosted blogs are off-topic, but they might be on-topic in [webmasters.com]. To learn about the complete list of [se] sites, go to https://stackexchange.com/sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you remember your FTP account password or your browse filesystem password? If so, FTP into the site, go into the directory you installed WordPress in and look for wp-config.php file. That contains your database's password in clear text.

Not sure what protects phpMyAdmin, but if that's .htaccess or .htpasswd, you can edit or delete that one.

Comment: Makes me wonder, isn't that so unsecure? To store a password in clear text?

Comment: Any system has a weakest link. If you have access to file system, you are beyond hope. But yes, cleartext password is not so good. A smart thing would have been to hash it on first use. But it is a little difficult since WordPress runs from scratch every time you request a page (no live memory outside of files/database/http-request content)